# XPath: How to select elements <FIELD> beneath <ITERATION>

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML document:

```
<TX value="com.igsapp.wibc.host.TxInfo">
<FORMAT>
    <RECORD id="RqHeader">
        <ITERATION id="Header" times="1">
            <FIELD id="Id"/>
            <FIELD id="CAppSeq"/>
            <FIELD id="CAGrpSeq"/>
            <ITERATION id="Status" times="1">
                <FIELD id="System"/>
                <FIELD id="SCode"/>
            </ITERATION>
            <ITERATION id="aaa" times="1">
                <FIELD id="bbb"/>
                <FIELD id="Sccc"/>
            </ITERATION>
        </ITERATION>
   </RECORD>
 </FORMATE>
 </TX>
```

I want to find every `FIELD` in the `RECORD` with ID of `RqHeader`.  I tried

```
/TX/FORMAT/RECORD[@id='RqHeader']/ITERATION/FIELD
```

but that only returned the three `FIELD` elements directly within the `RECORD`, not those within the `ITERATION`s.  How can I get all the fields?

Comment: So you want all `<FIELD>` beneath `<ITERATION>`... what's wrong with doing exactly that? `/TX/FORMAT/RECORD[@id='RqHeader']/ITERATION/FIELD`?

Comment: it only give me Id/CAppSeq/CAGrpSeq     , but I want to get Id,CAppSeq,CAGrpSeq, System,Scode,aaa,bbb,ccc

Comment: Ah. Use `/TX/FORMAT/RECORD[@id='RqHeader']//ITERATION/FIELD` for that. Note the double slash.

Comment: thank you Tomalak, it works!!!

Comment: bill - don't edit the question to add the solution - instead, write it as an answer.  (As a bonus, you can then earn points for both question and answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Request:** I want to find every FIELD in the RECORD with ID of RqHeader.

**Answer:**

```
//RECORD[@id='RqHeader']//FIELD
```

Or if you want to keep root layers in path:

```
/TX/FORMAT/RECORD[@id='RqHeader']//FIELD
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `//` operator to select nodes across nesting levels.

```
/TX/FORMAT/RECORD[@id='RqHeader']//ITERATION/FIELD
```

---

`//` actually is not really an operator, it's [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following expression, it works.

```
/TX/FORMAT/RECORD[@id='RqHeader']//ITERATION/FIELD
```